# Query related to Connection type BIS-B Socket in Blackberry application

Tags: blackberry, java-me, tcp, sockets, blackberry-storm

I am trying to establish BIS Socket connection. I am able to establish BIS Http connection from my service provider.

I have downloaded one chat application that checks network types supported by my device/service plan which has following list:

```
1)BIS-Http : OK
2)BIS-SOCKET :OK
3)BES-HTTP : NA
4)BES-SOCKET : NA
5)TCP-HTTP : BAD DNS
6)TCP-SOCKET : TIMED OUT
```

As I know direct TCP is not supported by my service provider. So I would like to use BIS-Socket connection.

Can anypne please help me in achieving this type of connectivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of BIS-B connectivity is available to members of the Blackberry Developer Alliance program. Not being a member I can't tell you if if supports random socket connection or not.

Normal BIS access available through the API supports web protocols and is not a TCP/IP protocol between the Blackberry and the BIS. Hence the deviceSide= parameter in the connection stream. DeviceSide=true the Blackberry uses an internal TCP stack to establish a connection through direct access to the wireless carrier's access point (APN). DeviceSide=false (the default) the Blackberry sends the necessary data to the BIS (or BES) MDS server using a presumably proprietary protocol. The MDS server then establishes the TCP connection on behalf of the Blackberry.

If direct TCP is not available to you, and you can't use BIS-B, you will have to carry your data on top of an http connection. In most cases this is straight forward and works quite well.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I think I wont be able to establish TCP connection with BIS without Alliance program membership.I need to work with Bis-http only at this point of time.Thanks again.

Comment: What do you mean by using Bis-http? I have an http connection and I want to assign to it BIS parameters and I have the same problem here. How can a Bis-http solve this? I doubt ...

Answer (score 0):

To use BIS you need pay $2000. Have you done that? how you know you're using BIS?