# Network Connection Issue + Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am facing a network connection issue. My client has sent me following mail and I am having no idea what I should do in this condition

"One of our companies have asked if it would be possible for them to use their apps with the data going via a proxy. The hve disabled WAP on their BES so they are unable to use the application. I think in this instance the data needs to be routed through the BIS."

For using BIS , I have read that application needs to be approved by RIM and we need to append    a secret String provided by the RIM to the connection URL.

For BES we append `;deviceside=false` in case of simulator.
For TCP we append `;deviceside=true` to the connection URL.
For Wifiwe append `;interface=wifi` to the connection URL.

What should we append in the case of BIS?

Comment: For using BIS , I have read that application needs to be approved by RIM and we need to append a secret String provided by the RIM to the connection URL ..... Where did you get this information? What is your reference?

Comment: yes, this is true - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686338/query-related-to-connection-type-bis-b-socket-in-blackberry-application/1688748#1688748

Comment: @Farid Farhat: I have read this some time before in Blackberry Support Forums. I don't have the link right now nut i remember that I read somewhere.

Comment: RIM may have relaxed this requirement, but I can't find any specific indication. I do know that if you regester a PUSH API application, the seample code uses BIS-B to connect to the push server.